# date change according to days but other month its not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have following function i used for date change according to my days its working fine when i used this month, but when i select month of October its show me wrong date. i spend 4 hours in this but not success any one help me this please

```
     <div class="col-md-3">
   <label>In Date</label>
   <div class="input-group date form_date " data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
  <input ng-model="HotelInDate" autocomplete="off" id="InDate" class="form-control input-height" placeholder="Date" type="text">
 <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
  </div>
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nights</label>
 <input ng-change="OutDate()" autocomplete="off" ng-model="HotelDetail.Nights" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="0">

 </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Out Date</label>
   <input readonly ng-model="MyOutdate" autocomplete="off" id="OutDate" class="form-control input-height" placeholder="Date" type="text">

 </div>
```

JS CODE

```
 $scope.OutDate = function () {
        var InDate = document.getElementById('InDate').value;
        var reversed = InDate.split('-').reverse().join('-');
        $scope.mydate = new Date(reversed);
        var modified = new Date();
      var nights =  parseInt($scope.HotelDetail.Nights, 10);
      modified.setDate($scope.mydate.getDate() + nights);
      var outdate = modified.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      var reversedoutdate = outdate.split('-').reverse().join('-');
      $scope.MyOutdate = reversedoutdate;

    }
```

[image: October Wrong Date]

[image]

Comment: You define `var modified = new Date();` and you only change the date (day of the month) which means that the month will always be the current month.

Comment: Also, why are you using `document.getElementById('InDate').value` when that input has a model ?

Comment: because when i select the date from date picker ng-model show me null value

Comment: Using `var modified = new Date($scope.mydate.getTime());` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to get new date in your scenario

```js
 $scope.OutDate = function () {
        var InDate = document.getElementById('InDate').value;
        var reversed = InDate.split('-').reverse().join('-');
        $scope.mydate = new Date(reversed);
      var nights =  parseInt($scope.HotelDetail.Nights, 10);
      $scope.mydate.setDate($scope.mydate.getDate() + nights);
      var outdate = $scope.mydate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      var reversedoutdate = outdate.split('-').reverse().join('-');
      $scope.MyOutdate = reversedoutdate;

    }
```